# Release mode APK do not work same as debug mode APK

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle, build, apk

I am facing an interesting problem. The problem is when I build my APK in debug or profile mode I can use the app, but in release mode, I can not. My app has a login screen, in release mode APK I type the username and password my Restful API (Web Service) returns a correct response and actually, I am logging in but page do not route, but the app does not route to the main page, When I try the same thing in other build modes (such as debug and profile) they work fine.

Comment: Can you check your logs to see if anything shows up?

Comment: Which logs? I am testing on a device.

Comment: Okay. You can connect the device to the computer and run  "flutter logs" to view the logs.

Comment: Thats right. But I can not run my project on release mode when try to run `flutter run --release` I get message `Release mode is not supported by AOSP on IA Emulator.`

Comment: You can't run your Flutter app in release mode on an Emulator. Try using a physical device.

Comment: You can actually connect your app to the computer via a USB device and open it normally. Just make sure you run "flutter logs" on the terminal. You can see the logs for the release on your physical device.